# audio data was altered when I use pyaudio write() to send to an usb audio device

Tags: usb, pyaudio, wave

I want to do some test with my usb audio device, and use pyaudio to send specific data.
the code snippets:

```
# Open the audio device.
stream = pyaudio.PyAudio().open(
    format=pyaudio.paInt16,
    channels=2,
    rate=48000,
    output=True,
)
# Create a sample data array
datas = []
for i in range(48000):
    datas.append(bytes.fromhex('0f0f0f0f'))

# Write the data to the audio device.
for d in tqdm(datas):
    stream.write(d)

# Close the audio device.
stream.close()

# Close the PyAudio object.
pyaudio.PyAudio().terminate()`
```

I captured usb packets using bushound, and found there are multiple bytes of zero prior the pattern "0f0f0f0f" were sent, and some "0x0f" bytes were changed to "0x10" or "0x0e" somehow.
what's the reason for this? USB UAC isn't a reliable transmission, maybe some bits alteration during transmission is normal?
Any advice or comments are highly appreciated, thanks!

when playing a wav file using pyaudio, the usb data is also slightly different with raw data in wav file.